# BottomTabNavigator not working in React Native

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-v5

I am using Drawer,Stack and Tab navigator using React Navigation 5, I have followed documentation but Tab Navigator not showing.
Here's my code:
In my app.js I have called my main StackNavigator:

```
const Stack = createStackNavigator();

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <NavigationContainer>
        <Stack.Navigator headerMode="none" initialRouteName="HomePage">
          <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomePage} />
          <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={LoginSignUp} />
          <Stack.Screen name="DrawerScreenss" component={DrawerScreens} />
          <Stack.Screen name="Tab" component={TabComp} />
        </Stack.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
    );
  }
}
```

This is my Drawer Navigation Code:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { createDrawerNavigator } from '@react-navigation/drawer';
import DrawerContent from './DrawerComponents/DrawerContent';
import DrawerHome from './DrawerComponents/DrawerHome';
const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();
export default class DrawerScreens extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Drawer.Navigator
        drawerContent={() => (
          <DrawerContent navigation={this.props.navigation} />
        )}>
        <Drawer.Screen name="DrawHome" component={DrawerHome} />
      </Drawer.Navigator>
    );
  }
}
```

Here's my **TabNavigator** which is not working:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs";
import DrawerHome from "./DrawerHome";
import Bookmarks from "./Bookmarks";

export default class TabComp extends Component {
  render() {
    const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();
    return (
      <Tab.Navigator
        initialRouteName="Home"
        tabBarOptions={{
          activeTintColor: "#e91e63",
          activeTintColor: "red",
          inactiveTintColor: "grey",
          style: {
            backgroundColor: "white",
            borderTopColor: "red"
          },
          labelStyle: {
            fontSize: 12,
            fontWeight: "normal"
          },
          indicatorStyle: {
            borderBottomColor: "red",
            borderBottomWidth: 4
          }
        }}
      >
        <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={DrawerHome} />
        <Tab.Screen name="Bookmarks" component={Bookmarks} />
      </Tab.Navigator>
    );
  }
}
```

It should be visible in my DrawerHome screens but not working

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what your `HomePage` component looks like, but it could look something like this with a button that navigates to your `DrawerScreens` screen:

```
const HomePage = ({navigation}) => {
  return (
    <View style={{flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center'}}>
      <Text>Feed Screen</Text>
      <Button
        title="Go to DrawerScreens"
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate('DrawerScreens')}
      />
    </View>
  );
};
```

The important thing I changed in your `DrawerScreens` component is that its screen is your `TabComp` component:

```
class DrawerScreens extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Drawer.Navigator
        drawerContent={() => (
          <DrawerContent navigation={this.props.navigation} />
        )}>
        <Drawer.Screen name="Tab" component={TabComp} />
      </Drawer.Navigator>
    );
  }
}
```

The `TabComp` component itself can stay the same.

Then inside your `DrawerHome` component you can trigger your drawer using `navigation.openDrawer()`.

```
const DrawerHome = ({navigation}) => {
  return (
    <View style={{flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center'}}>
      <Text>Feed Screen</Text>
      <Button title="Open Drawer" onPress={() => navigation.openDrawer()} />
    </View>
  );
};
```

This way you can show your tabs and your drawer at the same time.